# Letterbox Image and fill with empty space with another image

Tags: php, image, gd, scaling, image-scaling

I am currently using the GD php library to scale some images letterbox style and fill the resulting empty space with the color black.  I need however to fill the empty space using the pattern I have within another image file.  Any ideas on how to do this?

This is the code I am using to scale the images:

```
    function resize_image($source_image, $destination_width, $destination_height, $type = 0) {
    // $type (1=crop to fit, 2=letterbox)
    $source_width = imagesx($source_image);
    $source_height = imagesy($source_image);
    $source_ratio = $source_width / $source_height;
    $destination_ratio = $destination_width / $destination_height;
    if ($type == 1) {
        // crop to fit
        if ($source_ratio > $destination_ratio) {
            // source has a wider ratio
            $temp_width = (int)($source_height * $destination_ratio);
            $temp_height = $source_height;
            $source_x = (int)(($source_width - $temp_width) / 2);
            $source_y = 0;
        } else {
            // source has a taller ratio
            $temp_width = $source_width;
            $temp_height = (int)($source_width / $destination_ratio);
            $source_x = 0;
            $source_y = (int)(($source_height - $temp_height) / 2);
        }
        $destination_x = 0;
        $destination_y = 0;
        $source_width = $temp_width;
        $source_height = $temp_height;
        $new_destination_width = $destination_width;
        $new_destination_height = $destination_height;
    } else {
        // letterbox
        if ($source_ratio < $destination_ratio) {
            // source has a taller ratio
            $temp_width = (int)($destination_height * $source_ratio);
            $temp_height = $destination_height;
            $destination_x = (int)(($destination_width - $temp_width) / 2);
            $destination_y = 0;
        } else {
            // source has a wider ratio
            $temp_width = $destination_width;
            $temp_height = (int)($destination_width / $source_ratio);
            $destination_x = 0;
            $destination_y = (int)(($destination_height - $temp_height) / 2);
        }
        $source_x = 0;
        $source_y = 0;
        $new_destination_width = $temp_width;
        $new_destination_height = $temp_height;
    }
    $destination_image = imagecreatetruecolor($destination_width, $destination_height);
    if ($type > 1) {
        imagefill($destination_image, 0, 0, imagecolorallocate($destination_image, 0, 0, 0));
    }
    imagecopyresampled($destination_image, $source_image, $destination_x, $destination_y, $source_x, $source_y, $new_destination_width, $new_destination_height, $source_width, $source_height);
    return $destination_image;
}
```

Thank You

EDIT ------------------

I am now using this code which works perfectly, uses the methods suggested below:

```
        $destination_image = imagecreatetruecolor($destination_width, $destination_height);

    if ($type > 1) {
        if ($pattern != NULL) {
            $pattern = imagecreatefrompng($pattern);
            imagesettile($destination_image, $pattern);
            imagefill($destination_image, 0, 0, IMG_COLOR_TILED);
        } else {
            imagefill($destination_image, 0, 0, imagecolorallocate($destination_image, 0, 0, 0));
        }
    }
    imagecopyresampled($destination_image, $source_image, $destination_x, $destination_y, $source_x, $source_y, $new_destination_width, $new_destination_height, $source_width, $source_height);
    return $destination_image;
```

$pattern is a file path to the background image to fill the letter box with!

Comment: I am guessing from looking around that I want to use something like imagecopyresampled but I am not sure how I would do that.

Answer (score 0):

First prepare the background with [imagesettile()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagesettile.php) to create your tiled canvas to overlay your letter box onto, then copy the letterboxed part of the image into this resource using the source_x/y/w/h parameters of [imagecopy()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imagecopy.php) or [imagecopyresampled()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imagecopyresampled.php).

Comment: Thanks, I will read up on those methods and see if I can figure it out!